# File that exists is not being found in Java

Tags: java, file

I have a Java program that searches through your cookies files and then saves each file into an array. I then try to search through each of those files for a certain string, however when I try to search the files I KNOW exist, java tells me that they don't. Any ideas?

Here is my code so far:

```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.util.*;

   public class CheckCookie 
   {
      static String[] textFiles = new String[100];
        static String userName = "";

      public static void findCookies()
      {

         String path = "pathtocookies"; 

         String files;
         File folder = new File(path);
         File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

         for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
         {

            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
            {
               files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
               if (files.endsWith(".txt") || files.endsWith(".TXT"))
               {
                  textFiles[i] = files;
               }
            }
         }
      }

      public static boolean searchCookies()
      {
         for(int j = 0; j < textFiles.length; j++) {
                String path2 = "pathtocookies"+textFiles[j];
            File file = new File(path2);

            try {
               Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
               while (scan.hasNext()) {
                  String line = scan.nextLine();
                  if(line.contains("ineligible_age")) { 
                            System.out.println("A cookie for ineligible age was set.");             
                            return true;
                  }
               }

            } 
               catch(FileNotFoundException e) { 
               System.out.println("File was not found.");
                    return false;
               }
         }
            System.out.println("A cookie for ineligible age was not set.");
         return false;
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
         findCookies();
            searchCookies();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Finished searching for cookies. Yum.");
      }

   }
```

Actual path:

```
C:/Users/lucas.brandt/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Cookies
```

Comment: What permissions does user running this application on that file?

Comment: Are you on Windows and not escaping file paths correctly? Can you show us how your path actually looks like, because obviously there is a problem with it.

Comment: Have you stepped through using a debugger? setting a breakpoint where you are testing if a file exists?

Comment: The user should have admin permissions,and i put in the actual path.

Comment: Will try that really quick. Edit, that did not solve the problem.

Comment: @MarekSebera you only need the escaped `\\` if that path actually appears in your code. if it appears as a value in text somewhere, you do not need the escaping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a List, instead of an array to store the textFiles.

Imagine a directory with 2 files. The first is "abc.doc", the second "itsme.txt"

Your textFiles array will look like this:

- textFiles[0]: null
- textFiles[1]: "itsme.txt"

So you try to access "pathtocookies" + "null" which will fail, you go to the catch and return out of the function.

Further hints:

- Return the list from the first function, use it as an argument for the second function
- Use a debugger or "debug" print statements to debug your code to see whats happening

More hints depends on the actual use case.

--tb

Answer (score 3):

In this line:

```
String path2 = "pathtocookies"+textFiles[j];
```

You are missing the File separator between the directory name and the file name. java.io.File has a constructor that takes the parent path and the file name as separate arguments. You can use that or insert File.separator:

```
String path2 = "pathtocookies" + File.separator + textFiles[j];
```

You are also picking up directories in your array. Check that it is a file before you try to scan it.

Also, consider the other answer where the files are saved in a List, eliminating the directories.

Comment: Agreed. That is what I meant when I said to use the other constructor.

Comment: I tried this, but I am still receiving the file not found error. I don't think the issue lies within the path, so I would think this should have worked but it did not. I attempted the File.seperator that is.

Comment: @jalynn2 I can see that now, I misread your answer originally.

Comment: As this was also a help to the solution I upvoted your answer, however  tb- had more of a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
  files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
```

Try to change to

```
files = listOfFiles[i].getAbsolutePath();
```

**EDIT**
You can also initiate directectly an array of File (instead of String),
 and you have to use `.canRead()` method to verify File access.

Comment: when I tried your suggestion it resulted in this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:251)
 at CheckCookie.searchCookies(CheckCookie.java:37)
 at CheckCookie.main(CheckCookie.java:62)
`

Comment: @Twisterz and what about line 37 and 62 of ChechCookie ? post this code

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just store the `File` instances in a `File[]` or `List<File>`?

I think you would also benefot from using a StringBuilder, when doing a lot of string concatenstions...